# How to Upload modified data in Datagridview?

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have fetched some data from a SQL database into a datagridview, but after the user modified the data in the datagridview, how can I upload the data back?

And also, I found a code like this:

```
this.dataGridView1.Update();
```

What does this method Update? Here is the code where I bind the data to datagridview:

```
SqlDataReader read;
SqlCommand cmd;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Table", 204.192.49.3);
read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(read);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: how you load data to datagridview? can you update question with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a temporary DataSet, fill it with data using a SqlDataAdapter and then passing it as dataGridView's DataSource. This code should do the trick:
    `DataSet temp = new DataSet();
     SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
     SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
     string connstring = "YourConnectionString";`

And then in the method you want to trigger the update do this:

```
`connection.Open();
 command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table" //Adjust the SQL query to your needs
 command.Connection = connection;
 SDA.SelectCommand = command;
 SDA.Fill(temp);
 dataGridView1.DataSource = temp.Tables[0].DefaultView;`
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: What i want is to upload the data back to the sql server after modifing the data, but after i run your code, it seems that it fetch the sql server and blind the original data back to the datagrid view......

Comment: How do you modify your data. Do you do your modifications in the dataGridView directly, or do you use SQL queries?.

Comment: I do modifications in the DataGridView directly

Comment: In that case you can add a button column to your dataGridView that will trigger a SQL Update command. When you enter all the modifications you want and click the button, make a method that constructs the SQL command. It will look like this 
`UPDATE table_name SET column1 = '"dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString()+"'...`
The "e" is DataGridViewCellEventArg so it would be best to put this code into a OnCellClick or OnCellContentClick method of yourDataGridView. You call it only if the Cells[e.ColumnIndex] equals the index of the button.

Comment: Also you can transfer the data into a textBoxes and do your modifications there, and have another button that triggers the SQL command. In this case you use something like this:
`textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();`
You create a textBox for each column of your dataGridView and pass a single cell content to each textBox. When you do the modifications you want, click the button that has the SQL command - this time it will be 
`Update teble_name SET column1 = "+textBox1.Text+"....`

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you have fill your datagrid with Datasource property and SqlDataAdapter. You just have to update the adadpter object.

Answer (score 0):

you can not update yr grid with this "this.dataGridView1.Update();" code
you must bind your grid view to db after update your data in db

Comment: How can i blind the grid view to db?

Comment: I have done this at the beginning when i fetch data from the database, do i need to blind again when I upload the data back to the database

Comment: After you updating your data into data base you must bind your grid view to db again

Comment: "dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.Update();" is this code correct?

Comment: dataGridView1.DataSource=updatedquery, dataGridView1.Update()is not necessary

Comment: let me explain,for example after you remove or edit your record in your data base write a new query for getting updated information,after this set dataGridView1.DataSource equals your new query,your gridview records will be update

Comment: something like this  
'code' private void edit()
        {
            var query = CDataBase.QODB.TopicsTbls.Single(item => item.name == "Someting");
            query.Id = "new";
            CDataBase.QODB.SaveChanges();
            update();
        }
        private void update()
        {
            var updatedquery=CDataBase.QODB.TopicsTbls.Select(Item=>Item.name, ...)
            DataGridView.DataSource = updatedquery;
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridVies1_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
        SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
        sda.Update(ds);
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{

       private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.ConnectionString = connectionstr;

        sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from table_user", con);//define dataadapter
        sda.Fill(ds );
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];//bind the data，now the datagridview can show up the data

    }
    string connectionstr = "integrated security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=****;Data Source=localhost;";//init

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();//
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();//

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //you can not update sda here

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dataGridVies1_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);//auto generate the cmd of create, delete and update 
        sda.Update(ds);//flush to database
     }


}
```

Comment: When I use the code "SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);//auto generate the cmd of create, delete and update 
        sda.Update(ds);//flush to database", I come had an exception "The DataAdapter.SelectCommand property needs to be initialized.", what is it?

Comment: try add `sda.DeleteCommand = cb.GetDeleteCommand();
       sda.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
       sda.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand();` before you update your adapter.

Comment: i still got the exception.., after modifing the code, the code looks like:  SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);//auto generate the cmd of create, delete and update 
            da.DeleteCommand = cb.GetDeleteCommand(); da.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand(); da.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand();
            da.Update(dt);//flush to database